# Emacs 28 crashing when using triple quotes for docstrings

Tags: python, debug, crash

In Emacs 28, in python-mode, unbelievably, triple quotes causes emacs CPU utilization to hit 100% and freeze / crash.  Apparently a known error related to jit-lock-mode.

I'm asking the question here, and providing the answer, because I've seen this on reddit, twitter, etc., but no proper answer all in one place.

Comment: Is it "freeze" or "crash"?  Crashing means the process has died.  Freezing means it's still running but not responding.  A process which is consuming 100% CPU is very much still running (even if not behaving as desired).

Comment: I've experienced this too. And it is a freeze.

Answer (score 3):

For others who have run into this in Emacs 28, and have spent hours frustrated by it, as I did, the problem is a known bug and is fixed in emacs 29.

Follow this guide here: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/INSTALL

Download 29 here: https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/

Paste any errors into ChatGPT and follow directions :)

Comment: Thanks very much Marc, I kept getting hit by this and was vim-editing files.  Regards, jz